# How can I use a query result as a column for a separate query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query as below.

```
SELECT 'U_' + (LEFT(DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()), 3)) + 'Confirm'
```

This brings a result of, for instance, U_ThuConfirm

I then need to use that result as a column in a different query with that field in the table I am trying to query. as below;

```
SELECT ('U_' + (LEFT(DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()), 3)) + 'Confirm') FROM MyTable
```

I have tried variables, but it is just displaying the result, not actually checking that column.

Comment: is this SQL Server or MySQL? You have it tagged as both.

Comment: The syntax is clearly SQL Server, so I removed the mysql tag.

Comment: Your query should return one column for each row in `MyTable` that has the value you are looking for ("U_ThuConfirm").  Please edit your question and show your desired results, if this isn't what you want.

Comment: Hi,

Sorry about the mysql tag.

As for the desired results, I want to use, in this case, U_ThuConfirm as a column, so if I write SELECT U_ThuConfirm from MyTable, I should get whatever value sits there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need create a string that contains your query :

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(500)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT U_' + (LEFT(DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()), 3)) + 'Confirm FROM MyTable'
```

Then execute it like this

```
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this - where the choices are well-defined you can use a case statement

```
SELECT  CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, GetDate()) = 1 THEN U_SunConfirm
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, GetDate()) = 2 THEN U_MonConfirm
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, GetDate()) = 3 THEN U_TueConfirm
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, GetDate()) = 4 THEN U_WedConfirm
         ... etc
        END
        AS Confirms
```